# Is the COLUMN keyword in MySQL optional?

Tags: mysql, sql

In commands like the where the DROP clause is used

```
ALTER TABLE DROP <column>
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN <column>
```

are both accepted.

Are there any commands in which the COLUMN keyword is not optional or is it optional everywhere?

Comment: The answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

From [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html)

> The word COLUMN is optional and can be omitted, except for RENAME
> COLUMN (to distinguish a column-renaming operation from the RENAME
> table-renaming operation).

Answer (score 0):

It is clear in the [syntax reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html) where the `COLUMN` keyword is optional:

```
 | DROP [COLUMN] col_name
```

The square-brackets notation in the syntax reference means that the word inside the brackets is optional. See the linked documentation page for other cases of optional keywords.